# How to add explanation for a searched word?

Tags: support

In stackexchange sometimes when we search for a word, A short description appears. How can I add such a description for a word like "EMI" which stands for "Electromagnetic interference"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/tagging

This is handled by tags. Take a look.